# sonkeigo question: talking about 社長's daily life

Tags: grammar, keigo, sonkeigo

the exercise is to turn the bold part into sonkeigo (i'm talking about my 社長!! )
I'm confused cause I'm not sure how to change these phrases (and which verb to conjugate over another)

> 1. 社長が日本に**来るそうです。**

「社長が日本にいらっしゃるそうです。」?  Do i keep the そうです / ようです or does です turn into でいらっしゃる? I'm confused because i think it would be double keigo.

> 2. 明日は日本の社員に**会うことになっています。**

It would be お会いになる but then i would have two なる...

> 3. 週末にはゴルフを**するつもりだそうです.**

Here I'm lost (なさるつもりだそうです??)

> 4. 週末、アメリカに**帰ると言っていました。**

お帰りになるとおっしゃっていました。

Unfortunately my textbook mainly provided a table on how to conjugate simple verbs and not how to deal with indirect speech and whether or not keep そう、よう and です.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that you don't use sonkeigo when talking to people outside your company about your 社長, which means all the sentences below (your sentences + sonkeigo) are rather of limited use - one possibility I can imagine is: you are secretary and talking to someone significantly senior to you in YOUR company. If you are talking among (normal) colleagues, I don't think people USUALLY use keigo about your shacho really (may depend on how you talk usually though).

Basically your guesses are correct.

> 1.社長が日本に来るそうです。
>
> 1s.社長が日本にいらっしゃるそうです。

You can just turn the real verb part into sonkeigo: (見るそうです→ご覧になるそうです, 来たそうです→いらっしゃったそうです, etc.)

> 2.明日は日本の社員に会うことになっています。
>
> 2s.明日は日本の社員にお会いになることになっています。

Yes, なることになっている sounds clumsy while it's grammatically correct. Maybe different wording like お会いになる予定です is better. (This happens in many cases, you just have to rephrase it.)

> 3.週末にはゴルフをするつもりだそうです.
>
> 3s.週末にはゴルフをなさるつもりだそうです

Practically I think 週末(に)はゴルフの予定だそうです is fine (no issue for keigo because it is practically noun-only). Or 週末にはゴルフをなさるとのことです if you keep some keigo.

(Edit) As commented, you can add お to つもりです. But to me, it sounds 社長 is doing something serious (often negative to the addressee) or the speaker is criticizing. For example, ゴルフをなさるおつもりだそうです sounds *He is gonna play golf this weekend!! (which sounds absurd to me the speaker)* when the company is in some sort of emergency.

> 4.週末、アメリカに帰ると言っていました。
>
> 4s.週末、アメリカにお帰りになるとおっしゃってました

4s is okay, but 帰国されるとおっしゃってました sounds better. This is another instance of vocabulary choice - not really/exactly a keigo matter.

Comment: A secretary might say おつもり.

Comment: thank you so much :))